# Quick search for values in ranges

Tags: search, data-structures

Let's suppose that we have geoip database: `IPrangeStart`, `IPrangeEnd`, `country`.

```
#for, example
1.1.1.1:2.2.2.2:US
3.3.3.3:4.4.4.4:DE
```

etc.

This database have a lot of strings, but all this data can perfectly fit memory (about 200-500Mb). Now we need to find country by ip. What data structure fits best for doing it (we'll transfer all IP to int, of course)?

Comment: You can create 4 dimensional array in memory to hold every possible value from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255. By my calculation it will take approximately 8gb of memory but you'll get fastest search time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array that's sorted by the range start value will let you find the proper range with a simple binary search. I don't know how many address ranges you're working with, but even if you had a million ranges the binary search will take at most 20 probes. You could easily do tens of thousands of lookups per second with that.

Another option is a [segment tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree), although I don't see it being particularly helpful in this situation since you don't have overlapping intervals.